# 2D potential well problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, nuclear-physics, quantum-spin

[image]

Hi there I am having trouble answering both parts of this question. For (a), I was able to deduce that energy is well defined, but I don't know if this implies that linear momentum is well-defined along the x-axis.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Part(a) amounts to asking of the energy states are also eigenstates of $\hat p_x$.

Part (b) is a problem in counting states.

The ground state corresponds to $(n_x,n_y)=(0,0)$ and is the only state with energy $E_{0,0}=\hbar\omega$.  You can fit 2 protons there as they are fermions: one will have spin up the other will be spin down.

Next consider the first excited state, with total energy $2\hbar \omega$.  There are two $(n_x,n_y)$ states with this energy: $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$.  In each you can fit two protons to this gives you $4$ protons with $E_{1,0}=E_{0,1}=2\hbar \omega$.  You have now placed a total of $6$ protons: $4$ with $E=2\hbar \omega$ and $2$ with $E=\hbar \omega$.  The total energy of these $6$ protons is $2\times \hbar\omega+4\times 2\hbar\omega=10\hbar\omega$.

You can continue this way with states of total energy $3\hbar\omega$, then $4\hbar\omega$ etc until you exhaust all your protons.

Comment: Sorry why are all the energy states eigenstates of  p(hat), isn't p(hat) defined at -ihbar * d/dx ?

Comment: they are not eigenstates of $\hat p_x$.

Comment: So how do I setup the question for (a)? Because I don't know what psi(x,y) is. Normally, I would do phat *psi(x) = E * psi(x), but with the addition of an extra dimension it kind of confuses things.

Comment: $\psi_{n_x,n_y}(x,y)= H_{n_x}(x)H_{n_y}(y)$.